# CMD - how to write %

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I am using windows cmd and i am trying to do the following:

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug" /v debugger /t REG_SZ 
/d "%ENVIROMENT VAR%utils\cdb.exe  -pv -p %ld -c  """.dump /u /ma 
c:\utils\1.dmp;qd""" "

As you see, first enviroment varialbe is between % and is expanded by cmd, then %ld should be written as is. However, it is considered to be start of varialbe by CMD, so this fails.
I guess i need to add some escape character, but it failed.

How to set this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a caret (^) to escape the % so the problematic line becomes:

REG_SZ /d "%ENVIROMENT VAR%utils\cdb.exe -pv -p ^%ld -c """.dump /u /ma c:\utils\1.dmp;qd""" "

Paddy

Comment: The cmd.exe syntax is so esoteric

Comment: Very odd - which OS? 

Also are you typing this into the command line directly or using a bat file (from memory %% works from a file, ^ if you're typing it in directly.

Comment: Win2008 server.
Yes this is from a file.

Thanks.